# Interogate a remote iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

I am using LinkedIn buttons on a site, and these are pulled in via iframes.  The content is visitor specific, like a "Follow" button will say "FollowUs" or "Followed" depending on whether the visitor is already following the company.

LinkedIn have been throwing random 403 errors for these buttons for a couple of months, and I have been trying to work out a way to degrade gracefully when it fails.

Because of domain security, it seems like there is little I can do. I can't do a server-side test prior to sending the page to the browser, because the request needs to come from the user.  I can't do an ajax call to get the content, then render it myself, because it is cross domain.  I can't see whether the contents of the iframe is an error because it is cross domain.

Linkedin themselves don't do a nice degrade either - they just put up their "LinkedIn is having intermittent issues", with their big logo, which only a part of appears in the space that the iframe button would occupy.  It just looks messy.

I would like to suppress the iframe until I know it is right, or alternatively get rid of it if it doesn't contain what I want (display:none), but I can't see a way to workaround the domain issues.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the source of the iframe on your domain? If not, maybe find a non-iframe alternative.

Comment: @twiz The source of the frame is linkedin, as per the question.  I would welcome a non-frame suggestion if you have one.

Comment: Well I decided to see what I could find and this seems to be the only option: https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/follow-company

I assume this is what you are already using? Anyway, I found a related thread: https://developer.linkedin.com/thread/1824

A Linkedin employee said they were working on an alternative 2 years ago, but apparently they never finished it.